# Saving entire content of ScrollView as bitmap not ok as expected

Tags: android, android-bitmap

It shows visible area ok but invisible area are black background as shown below :

[image]

This is how I am saving the view

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int totalHeight, int totalWidth) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth,totalHeight , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Is your app hardware accelerated?

Comment: Hum...Then I guess we will need more information on how you're converting your view to bitmap. If you set a white background to it does it work?

Comment: @PedroOliveira please check the code how I am saving view

Comment: Try calling `canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), 255, Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG)` before you draw on it

Comment: Or call `canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);` after you instantiate your canvas to set transparency.

Comment: @PedroOliveira didn't worked

Comment: Could you force drawing white on canvas first and then draw the view? Also you might need to override the draw method of your view to force transparency/hardware accelerated rendering by calling setLayerType

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76165/discussion-between-rustam-and-pedro-oliveira).

Comment: Thanks Pedro by doing `canvas.drawARGB(255,255,255,255);` after canvas instantiate it worked fine..